# Tensorflow/Keras: Output shape mismatch in training data and predicted data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have an LSTM model defined in tensorflow/keras as below. I am including only the relevant details pertaining to the question.

```
t_steps = 60
n_features = 3

def LSTMModel():
  input = Input(shape=(t_steps, n_features))
  l1 = BatchNormalization()(input)
  l2 = LSTM(160,return_sequences=True)(l1)
  l3 = LSTM(80,return_sequences=True)(l2)
  l4 = LSTM(10,return_sequences=True)(l3)
  l5 = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(l4)
  model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = l5)
  model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer='adam')
  return model

# shape of X_train_seq is (275268, 60, 3)
# shape of Y_train_seq is (275268,)

model = LSTMModel()
model.fit(X_train_seq, Y_train_seq, epochs=n_epochs,
  batch_size=batch_size,verbose=1,initial_epoch=init_epoch)
```

Then when I predict using this model on a X_test_seq of shape (30355, 60, 3), I get Y_test_seq_pred of shape (30355, 60, 1) while I expect the prediction of shape (30355,). This happened because my l4 line in the above code should have been

```
l4 = LSTM(10,return_sequences=False)(l3)
```

My question is, with the original code, why didnt Tensorflow/Keras give an error or produce any sort of warning during training as the shape of Y_train_seq that is passed to the fit() method is (275268,) and during training, it must have been internally predicting a Y of shape (batch_size, 60, 1) for every batch during optimization and comparing it with a slice of shape (batch_size,) from Y_train_seq. How come this dimension mismatch in Y still let the code continue only for me to find out about it at the end of the training?
I am sure there must be some reason behind it and I want to know what is going on.
Thank you!!

Comment: I created a sample code on google colab suspecting that this may be related to tf/keras version. With default versions on colab (Keras 2.3.1, tf 2.2.0) it did throw me an error about dimension mismatch. Then to cross check, I installed Keras 2.2.4 (which is what my machine has) and the code executed fine without any error. To finish the A-B-A test, I reinstalled Keras 2.3.1 on google colab expecting it to throw me an error but it still executed fine without saying anything about dimensions. This leaves me very confused.

Answer (score 0):

That's occurs due to what's called on **Numpy** broadcasting, which describes how Numpy treats arrays with different shapes.

Let first define two tensors **A** and **B** tensors with the following shapes,

```
dim(A) = (32, 60, 1)
dim(B) = (32,)
```

For example, if you try to do some operations such **subtraction**, **addition** or any **element-wise** operation between **A** and **B**, in such case the way how **Tensorflow** represent **B** dimensions, something like replacing dimensions with don't care.

`dim(B) = (do_not_care, do_not_care, 32)`

So at iteration, scalar value x subtracted from an array of 32 elements (values), Therefor the output is a column matrix contains 32 different values.

`dim(output) = (32, 60, 32)`, which is valid, but unexpected behavior.

Such operation could be implemented **recursively**, we are iterating through the tensor with a higher dimension, starting from the **1st** dimension (**axis**)  to the known dimension of the second tensor, then we can apply the required operation to the resultant **chunked** tensor, if their shapes match, in other words the broadcasting **succeeds**.

---

The the implementation of a broadcasting  for **subtraction** could be done as follows.

```
def supstract(a, b): # a and b are numpy.array()

  # check if shape valid
  if a.squeeze().ndim == b.squeeze().ndim:
    if b.squeeze().shape[-1] == b.squeeze().shape[-1]:
      print(a - b, '\n')
      return
    else:
      raise ValueError(f'could not Broadcasting, {a.shape} != {b.shape}')

  elif a.ndim > b.ndim:
    for sub_a in a:
      supstract(sub_a, b) # recursive call
  else:
    for sub_b in b:
      supstract(a, sub_b) # recursive call
```

I have used the following example to check the implementation, so I may have missed some conditions (different cases handling).

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 4, (2, 2, 6, 1))
b = np.random.randint(1, 4, (4, ))
```

---

In your case **Tensorflow** need Y to compute the loss function , you are using **MSE** which just a scalar value, computed using **Keras** backend as follows.

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.mean((y_pred - y_true) ** 2) # broadcasting (y_pred - y_true)
```

---

### Update

```
|1 2 3| + |7 8 9|
|4 5 6|

|1 2 3| + 7 = |8  9  10|
|4 5 6|       |11 12 13|
```

Based on the **Tensorflow** documentation for describing the [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/broadcasting). **Numpy** (broadcasting) handle any of the above operations, but **mathematically** you can't apply any of them. If you want to have warning for any broadcasting operation, you might expect to get **tons** of warnings.

Comment: Hi @m-zayan Thank you. Even if python proadcasting is letting if happen, the question is why isnt there any warning. This is not a real issue for me as I have a correct code but was just curious.

Comment: Hi Makarand, The problem is, broadcasting is a valid operation, so getting warnings sometimes not reasonable, at least for how Numpy and Tensorflow treat arrays, the broadcasting means a lot for many operations as it's solves a lot problems and avoid getting errors and a lot of warnings.especially for tensorflow getting a warning for tensor with N dimensions, not too much helpful (numpy and tensorflow likes to have a generic solution), you can easily handle exception while building your model and preprocessing you dataset.

Comment: Makarand, I have updated the answer, hope it's help

Comment: Hi m-zayan: See the comment I added to the original question. Although broadcasting is a reasonable operation, in ML application, it is problematic if the output given by the model differs from the target provided to it.